# How to run an activity or service after 3 unsuccessful unlock attempt

Tags: android

I want to start my application when the user unable to unlock the phone after 3 attempt.
Like the app [Hidden Eye](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.midasensemble.hiddeneye&hl=en) is doing that it's able to take photo.
Can it be possible with BroadcastReceiver ? Any idea or example will be great.
I search a lot but did not find any article on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer and yes it can be done with BroadcastReceiver  with the action
[ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html#ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED)